# INKSCAPE: Bluring inside of objects

Tags: inkscape

I am having trouble containing a blur to the inside of an object which is the objective of this [Inner Shadow Effect Tutorial](https://youtu.be/X1SGxjMWbZs). In the tutorial he clips an offset of a matching shape which he blurs. His blurring results in a crisp outer edge with blurring to the inside of the object, hence giving an "Inner Shadow Effect". Mine maintains a crisp edge on the inside of the offset overlap and blurring to the outside of the object.

I have tried to change the settings in the Filter Editor/General Settings which did not resolve the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linked tutorial made a hole to a rectangle. The hole was made by subtracting a letter A-like shape from the rectangle. After the rectangle got the hole it was blurred.  Another A-like shape was used as a clipping mask which hided everything of the rectangle except the hole which has got some blur. The blur was layered on a third A and it looked like an inner shadow. The tutorial works, you have missed something.

The next is a shortened version of the principle:

[image]

Here's three A letters and a rectangle. The red is used to make a hole, the green is used to clip only the blurred hole interior to stay visible and the cyan A has got the blur as layered shape above it. Actually I placed the green A a little aside to get more black in the left side.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, and it seems to work as expected. See example below.

[image]

It's quite hard to tell exactly where you might have gone wrong, but I suspect you aren't blurring the black shape, and you are blurring the underlying grey letter instead. You need to make sure you have the black shape selected before you blur it.

Check you have the black shape selected by checking its fill colour at the bottom left corner of the screen (shown highlighted in red below)

[image]

Comment: You are correct. I come from a cad background and am very new to the logic of inkscape. When I followed his steps, for reasons unknown to me at this point, it is the red A the remained as the overlap. I'll take some time to figure out why/what I did wrong. So the issue sounds like it has to do with the order so to speak of the parts...maybe what's on top vs what's on bottom and in between. I really do appreciate the time you took to look into this. I'm gonna study your solution, till I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Filters > Shadows and Glows > Drop Shadow ... - no need for clipping.

[image: inner shadow]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. He mentioned the filter at the beginning of the tutorial and that his method allowed for a more controlled shadow effect than the filter mentioned. I'm hoping to get some understanding of inkscapes logic of his tutorial because I got the opposite response of the blur than he did. I'll play around with drop shadow too. Thanks for the insight.